# Why does the for loop created from this script remove all the elements instead of the indexes specified?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

Right now I'm doing an exercise involving a list the user makes that fills up with string values. The list is made and contains a length of 5 different values. This was the code that creates that list described above.

```
make_list = []

for x in range(5):
    x = input('Please give me some random words: ')
```

After words, what I'd like to do for my Python script is remove the 0th, 4th, and 5th elements in that list. Once done, I'm left with just two words from that list created. Here's the part of the code that I created.

```
def new_list(alist):
    for x in range(len(alist)):
        if x == 0 or x == 3 or x == 4:
            alist.pop(x)

    return alist
```

Then I invoked the function using the list created above.

```
print(new_list([make_list]))
```

What I always end up with on pycharm is just an empty list shown. []

What exactly am I missing in the whole script written down below that is causing this whole thing to pop/remove all of the list instead of indexes specified.

```
  make_list = []

for x in range(5):
    x = input('Please give me some random words: ')

def new_list(alist):
    for x in range(len(alist)):
        if x == 0 or x == 3 or x == 4:
            alist.pop(x)

    return alist

print(new_list([make_list]))
```

***EDIT***

Still getting that empty list thing going on.
Here's the updated code I typed.

```
make_list = []

for x in range(5):
    x = input('Please give me some random words: ')
    make_list.append(x)

def new_list(alist):
    for x in range(len(alist)):
        if alist.index(alist[x]) == 0  or alist.index(alist[x]) == 3 or alist.index(alist[x]) == 4:
            alist.remove(alist[x])

    return alist

print(new_list([make_list]))
```

Comment: Inspect `alist` in `new_list`. You are passing it a list containing `make_list`. You want `new_list(make_list)` or `new_list(list(make_list))`. You also have an issue with your loop in `new_list`. See if you can figure out what it is after fixing this first thing.

Comment: I deleted my answer because this question is proving to be far too broad. There are multiple issues with the code preventing it from working. You'll need to narrow the question down.

Comment: remove the square brackets in your print statement on the last line and you will get the list index out of range error that happens when you remove items from a list as you iterate in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution creating another list for the output.

```
make_list = []

for x in range(5):
    make_list.append(input('Please give me some random words: '))

def new_list(alist):
    out_list = []
    for i, x in enumerate(alist):
        if i not in [0, 3, 4]:
            out_list.append(x)

    return out_list

print(new_list(make_list))
```

[image]

Probably the fact that you get an empty list is that as 'alist' is shortened the indices points to different entries from the ones you would expect. A simple solution to problems like this is to create another list and leave the input list as is during the iteration. This should be true also for dicts and other mutables.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that you are calling the function with your list as the only item inside another list.

```
print(new_list([make_list]))
```

This other list is what you are getting back.
Funnily enough, you made this mistake again after the edit.

After you fix that silly mistake, you will run into another one. This one has to do with the size of the list versus the indices you want to remove. Think to yourself, "*What is index 4 after I have only 3 items left in my list?*"

To fix this one, you will have to rethink your approach all together - just using the indices will not cut it anymore.

*Actually the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896796/2089675) below mine (from [`Diego Sacconi`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5503859/diego-sacconi)) is a good way to solve this.*